# Pagination is not working inside nested scroll view in android java

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am building an app where i am fetching the data from firestore and want to use pagination but the problem is that the pagination is not working in nested scroll view. the code is something like this

My XML Code is something like this:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_on_24red"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24"
                android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_bhai"
                android:text="Your Location"
                android:textColor="#050505"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/searchbardesign"
                android:focusable="false"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:queryHint="search here eg. rooms in delhi... " />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeFreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <org.imaginativeworld.whynotimagecarousel.ImageCarousel
                    android:id="@+id/carousel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    app:autoPlay="false"
                    app:autoPlayDelay="3000"
                    app:autoWidthFixing="true"
                    app:carouselType="SHOWCASE"
                    app:imageScaleType="fitXY"
                    app:infiniteCarousel="true"
                    app:scaleOnScroll="false"
                    app:scalingFactor="0.15"
                    app:showBottomShadow="false"
                    app:showCaption="false"
                    app:showNavigationButtons="false"
                    app:showTopShadow="false"
                    app:touchToPause="true" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/roomsRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                   android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_slide_from_bottom"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_progress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My Java code is something like this there is method paginationcode() in which i have written pagination code and then in the oncreate method i have written the other code

```
  // this is the code i have written inside onCreate

         recyclerViewRooms.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

 nestedScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {

                View view = (View) nestedScrollView.getChildAt(nestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);

                int diff = (view.getBottom() - (nestedScrollView.getHeight() + nestedScrollView
                        .getScrollY()));

                if (diff == 0) {
                    // your pagination code

                    paginationCode();

                }
            }
        });

// this is the method code

  public void paginationCode()
   {
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query productsRef =  firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup("room_details");
    Query query = productsRef.orderBy("location", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(limit);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {


            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                for (DocumentSnapshot d : task.getResult()) {
                    RoomsDetails obj = d.toObject(RoomsDetails.class);
                    roomsDetails.add(obj);
                }

                roomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            lastVisible = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);

            RecyclerView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                        isScrolling = true;
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                    int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();


                    if (isScrolling && (firstVisibleItemPosition + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) && !isLastItemReached) {
                        isScrolling = false;

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        Query nextQuery = productsRef.orderBy("location", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).startAfter(lastVisible).limit(limit);
                        nextQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> t) {
                              

                                if (t.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot d : t.getResult()) {
                                        RoomsDetails productModel = d.toObject(RoomsDetails.class);
                                        roomsDetails.add(productModel);
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "hey this is", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    roomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    lastVisible = t.getResult().getDocuments().get(t.getResult().size() - 1);


                                    if (t.getResult().size() < limit) {
                                        isLastItemReached = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            };

            recyclerViewRooms.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: "the pagination is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors? Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-paginate-firestore-using-paging-3-on-android-c485acb0a2df) will help.

Comment: no sir the problem is that if we set limit to 5 then only 5 items fetch after that it does not fetch any item but if we use it without nested scroll view in a simple layout it works but it is not working in nested scroll view but we need that inside nested

Comment: Did you already debug the problem locally? For example: if you set a breakpoint on the second pagination query, run the code in a debugger, and check `lastVisible` does that have the value that you expect it to have?